# Rancher 2.6.3 Monitoring -> Dashboard ->Resource Unavailable

Tags: rancher

I set up a K8S cluster, a master node, and three nodes,like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy25k.png)

I enabled cluster monitoring under the system

However, when I hover over Monitoring ->Dashboard, all connections cannot be clicked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COowP.png)
And I can't find the relevant configurations of Prometheus and Grafana
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkhSO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XIdb.png)

My installation environment：
rancher-server   centos7.6
k8s-master       centos7.8
k8s-node(1,2,3)  centos7.8

and my docker version:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI06U.png)
I have tried to install it many times, and even re install it after all formatting,but still..
It is worth mentioning that：
During my installation,This problem will occur

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXUpS.png)

Until timeout,And there will be two red 'X' after name,and error message is

containers with unready status: [helm proxy]

But soon after the timeout,It disappeared and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwYf7.png)

This has bothered me for many days. I don't know how to do it or what problems

Hope to get help,THANKS

I tried to redeploy and restart the docker and rancher,But everything remains the same

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVxrB.png)